# Link between sum of squares and sum of absolutes

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, statistics, vector-spaces, vectors

If I have a real-valued vector $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, \cdots, x_p)$. Is there a way I can obtain $\sum_{i=1}^p \left|x_i \right|$ from $\sum_{i=1}^p \left|x_i \right|^2$?

Comment: Kind of! You can get bounds, like $(\sum |x_i| \cdot 1)^2 \leq (\sum |x_i|^2) (\sum 1^2)$ by [Cauchy-Schwarz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).

Comment: @prets Does that mean I could say $\sum_{i=1}^p \left|x_i \right| \leq \sum_{i=1}^p \left|x_i \right|^2$?

Comment: No, the sum $\sum 1^2 = p$ in your case, since we have $p$ terms! So $\sum |x_i| \leq \sqrt{p \sum |x_i|^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

[image]

In the picture $x^2+y^2=1$ but we can see that $|x|+|y|$ can take multiple values.

We can get some bounds from Cauchy-Schwarz:

$$\|x\|_2\le \|x\|_1 \le \sqrt{p}\|x\|_2$$

Comment: (I can't be the only person who finds the $1.4$ in place of $\sqrt{2}$, with the resulting intersections between the circle and square, slightly irksome... :) )

Comment: let me change to $\sqrt{2}$. :P